# Converting JSON string array into c# List object returning "null" value for each field of a Model inside a List

Tags: c#, arrays, json, list, json.net

I have list of JSON array in string format,and trying to convert in List of  c# Model.

I am using below line of code but its returning **null** value for each field of Model.Its showing correct count in line "objectList.Count" but when debugging the list array its showing "null" value for every field of Model.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
public partial class TestPage : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         ProfileDetailViewModel viewModel = new ProfileDetailViewModel();
        viewModel.ProfileDetailModelList = new List<ProfileDetailModel>();
        string content = @"[{""AccountNumber"":""1"",""CompressedAddress"":""1,  TEST,  READING,  Postcode"",""MType"":""10"",""BillNotification"":""Y"",""NewBillAlert"":""N"",""AccountType"":""1234568""}]";
        List<ProfileDetailModel> objectList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<ProfileDetailModel>>(content);
        if (objectList.Count > 0)
        {
            viewModel.Success = true;
            viewModel.ProfileDetailModelList = objectList;
        }
    }

}
public class ProfileDetailViewModel
{
    public List<ProfileDetailModel> ProfileDetailModelList { get; set; }
    public bool Success { get; set; }
}
public class ProfileDetailModel
{
    string AccountNumber { get; set; }
    string CompressedAddress { get; set; }
    string MType { get; set; }
    string BillNotification { get; set; }
    string NewBillAlert { get; set; }
    string AccountType { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All the properties on ProfileDetailModel are private. You can check the default visibility for clases, structs, etc... here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ba0a1yw2.aspx

Simply add `public`

```
public class ProfileDetailModel
{
       public string AccountNumber { get; set; }
       public string CompressedAddress { get; set; }
       public string MType { get; set; }
       public string BillNotification { get; set; }
       public string NewBillAlert { get; set; }
       public string AccountType { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should change all your properties ibn the model class to be `public`:

```
public class ProfileDetailModel
{
    public string AccountNumber { get; set; }
    public string CompressedAddress { get; set; }
    public string MType { get; set; }
    public string BillNotification { get; set; }
    public string NewBillAlert { get; set; }
    public string AccountType { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add JsonProperty attribute to all the properties. Refer the below screenshot.

```
public class ProfileDetailModel
{
    [JsonProperty]
    string AccountNumber { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty]
    string CompressedAddress { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty]
    string MType { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty]
    string BillNotification { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty]
    string NewBillAlert { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty]
    string AccountType { get; set; }
}
```